# removing duplicate include paths in android makefile

Tags: android, makefile, ndk-build

I have a complicated set of android make files that include each other.
As a result, `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` of the main make file becomes very long with many duplicates of the same paths.

Is there some way to remove duplicates, perhaps by calling some function?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling a python script via shell. The script takes the current value of `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` and returns it without duplicated paths, like this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(shell python -c "import sys;print(' '.join(set(sys.argv[1].split())))" "$(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)")
```